# Matrix classes in c++

Tags: c++, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm doing some linear algebra math, and was looking for some really lightweight and simple to use matrix class that could handle different dimensions: 2x2, 2x1, 3x1 and 1x2 basically.
I presume such class could be implemented with templates and using some specialization in some cases, for performance.
Anybody know of any simple implementation available for use? I don't want "bloated" implementations, as I'll running this in an embedded environment where memory is constrained.

Thanks

Comment: This is another complete lib, but probably too big as-well (called **eigen**): http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Eigen is definitely the best library. It's not too big and most important is templatized and optimized for small fixed size matrices.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [Blitz++](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/) -- or [Boost's uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm)

Comment: Both of these are fine.  I use Boost's version since the syntax is simpler; though I believe blitz is still somewhat faster.  Note that most benchmarks focus on large matrices, where fancy memory access patterns matter due to caching - for this kind of tiny matrix it probably won't.  Both are in any case fairly light-weight: the extensive api is almost all compile-time templating: your compiled code won't contain any unnecessary extra fields, checks or code.

Comment: Thanks, but those are somewhat bigger than what I'd need. I just need some few cases only (4 as I described above) so using a complete lib is too much. Probably I'm looking for some more hobby-like implementation, that provided the basic cases. Maybe I'll have to do my own..

Comment: It's up to you, but I'd note it's almost always quicker to use a library. (Though for a hobby, you'll learn more doing it yourself, of course.) Boost has a fantastic reputation, and you'll get more than just uBLAS -- I recommend having a look at their other offerings. BOOST_FOREACH alone is worth the download.

Comment: Sounds like a weekend project.

Comment: @AI: All these libraries are pure template libraries, so in terms of memory you only pay for the parts you use. Caveat: I'm pretty much a beginner with C++ templates, so you may wish to check.

Answer (score 5):

I've recently looked at a variety of C++ matrix libraries, and my vote goes to [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/).

- The library is heavily templated and header-only.
- Armadillo also leverages templates to implement a delayed evaluation framework (resolved at compile time) to minimize temporaries in the generated code (resulting in reduced memory usage and increased performance).
- However, these advanced features are only a burden to the compiler and not your implementation running in the embedded environment, because most Armadillo code 'evaporates' during compilation due to its design approach based on templates.
- And despite all that, one of its main design goals has been ease of use - the API is deliberately similar in style to Matlab syntax (see the comparison table on the site).

Additionally, although Armadillo can work standalone, you might want to consider using it with LAPACK (and BLAS) implementations available to improve performance. A good option would be for instance [OpenBLAS](http://xianyi.github.com/OpenBLAS/) (or [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/)). Check [Armadillo's FAQ](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html), it covers some important topics.

A quick search on Google dug up [this presentation](http://www.fordiac.org/fileadmin/pdf/etfa_2012/6_Hegny_Embedded_Energy_Efficiency_Industrial_Controller_Platform.pdf) showing that Armadillo has already been used in embedded systems.

Answer (score 1):

std::valarray is pretty lightweight.

Comment: I'd need something more than raw arrays, like dimension checking (ie. multiplying 1x2 with 2x2 matrix is ok, but 2x1 with 2x2 is not), otherwise I'd almost do it manually..

Answer (score 1):

I use [Newmat libraries](http://www.robertnz.net/nm_intro.htm) for matrix computations.  It's open source and easy to use, although I'm not sure it fits your definition of lightweight (it includes over 50 source files which Visual Studio compiles it into a 1.8MB static library).

Answer (score 1):

[CML](http://www.cmldev.net/) matrix is pretty good, but may not be lightweight enough for an embedded environment. Check it out anyway: http://cmldev.net/?p=418

Answer (score 1):

Another option, altough may be too late is:

https://launchpad.net/lwmatrix

Answer (score 0):

I for one wasn't able to find simple enough library so I wrote it myself: http://koti.welho.com/aarpikar/lib/

I think it should be able to handle different matrix dimensions (2x2, 3x3, 3x1, etc) by simply setting some rows or columns to zero. It won't be the most fastest approach since internally all operations will be done with 4x4 matrices. Although in theory there might exist that kind of processors that can handle 4x4-operations in one tick. At least I would much rather believe in existence of such processors that than go optimizing those low level matrix calculations. :)

Answer (score -1):

How about just store the matrix in an array, like

```
2x3 matrix = {2,3,val1,val2,...,val6}
```

This is really simple, and addition operations are trivial. However, you need to write your own multiplication function.