# library for matrices in c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a lot of elements in a matrix and when I access them manually it takes a pretty long time to eliminate all the bugs arising from wrong indexing... Is there a suitable library that can keep track of e.g the neighbors,the numbering, if an element is in the outer edge or not and so on.

e.g.

```
VA=
11 12 13 14
21 22 23 24
31 32 33 34
41 42 43 44
```

Now what I would like to do is write a function that says something like

```
for every Neighbor to element at index 12(which would be 41)
 do something
```

I would like this to only recognize the elements at index 8 (31) and 13 (42).

Right now I'm using vectors (`vector<vector<int>>V;`)but the code gets pretty difficult and clumsy both to write and read since I have these annoying if statements in every single function.
example:

```
     for (int i=0;i<MatrixSIZE;i++)
        if ((i+1)%rowSize!=0){//check that it's not in the outer edge.
    //Do something
}
```

What approach would you suggest?
Can boost::MultiArray help me here in some way? Are there any other similar?

UPDATE::
So i'm  looking more for a template that can easily access the elements than a template that can do matrix arithmetichs.

Comment: Have you tried going with a single vector and mapping its items to different rows/columns ? You can represent about any matrix in a linear way. You just have to keep information about width or height and do the computation `item(x,y) = m_items[x + y * m_width]` when you want to access one particular element.

Comment: And wrapping it all up in a class would be even better.

Comment: @ereOn & PeterK !
Aha! This seems like a good way of doing it, especially if I wrap it in a class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this: http://osl.iu.edu/research/mtl/

or this: http://www.robertnz.net/nm_intro.htm

If you Google it a bit, there's quite a few matrix libraries out there for C++.

Answer (score 1):

Try [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), a linear algebra package.

Answer (score 0):

This might inspire you:

[Matrix classes in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280474/matrix-classes-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Is it used in a larger program ? If not, it would be more adapted to use [R](http://www.r-project.org/) to deal with matrices.

If it's in a larger program, you can use a lib such as [MTL](http://osl.iu.edu/research/mtl/).